# Как разрешить автозапуск в Android 10?

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, автозапуск

Пишу приложение которое должно автоматически запускаться вместе с системой. Android 10 этого не позволяет пока пользователь не передвинет вот этот тумблер "Автозапуск". Тестировал в эмуляторе, там всё успешно запускается бродкаст и все уведомления. На реальном устройстве эта проблема. Спасибо заранее! Помогите пожалуйста)

Вот тот самый тумблер "Автозапуск".

[image: Тумблер]

Мой код: Receiver

```
 <receiver
            android:name="com.chistoedet.android.demonotifacation.BootCompletedIntentReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Broadcast:

```
class BootCompletedIntentReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        StringBuilder().apply {
            append("Action: ${intent.action}\n")
            append("URI: ${intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)}\n")
            toString().also { log ->
                Log.d("RECEIVER123", log)
                showNotification(context,intent)
                Toast.makeText(context, log, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }}
```

Comment: Автоматически никак. Только уведомить пользователя, что для вашей программы это жизненно необходимо и предложить перейти в настройки, где пользователь сам решит, нужно ему это или нет.

Comment: Больше скажу, во многих прошивках UI этого пункта совсем нет, например на Samsung

Comment: Хммм, спасибо за ответ! Хотя телеграмм и официальное приложение ВК не подчиняются этим моим тумблеркам...